# Next.js Tailwindcss Sass compilation issue

Tags: javascript, sass, next.js, frontend, tailwind-css

I built a basic template from tailwind for Next.js.

I usually use Tailwind's `@layer components` to add custom css code

But this time I wanted to use Sass and changed the globals.css to globals.scss when I encountered an error

> error - ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[9].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[9].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[9].use[3]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/sass-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[9].use[4]!./styles/globals.scss
> SassError: expected "{".
> ╷
> 12 │     @apply text-white w-screen #-{important} h-screen #-{important} font-["-apple-system","poppins"];
> │

here is my `globals.scss`:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "./components/Header/Header.module.css";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

@layer base {
  body {
    @apply text-white w-screen #-{important} h-screen #-{important} font-["-apple-system","poppins"];
  }

  a {
    @apply active:bg-[#ffffff]/20 #-{important}  focus:bg-[#ffffff]/20;
  }
}
@layer components {
  .filter-white {
    filter: invert(93%) sepia(91%) saturate(32%) hue-rotate(336deg)
      brightness(107%) contrast(99%);
  }

  .navbar {
    @apply p-0 #-{important} min-h-[4px]  !bg-[#141414]/20 backdrop-blur-lg text-sm leading-[4px] #-{important};
  }
}
```

`tailwind.config.js`:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
        "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

Help a fellow Out!

Comment: the #-{important} is what i found from tailwind docs but doesnt seem to help out the issue

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you donot have sass package installed.

Use `npm install --save-dev sass` or `yarn add -D sass` to use the functionality of sass in nextjs

Refer https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i do have sass installed
in the package.json :   "sass": "^1.53.0",